# Change server location for Automate Build in TFS

Tags: tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2008. my TFS is installed on one server and I want to copy builds of automate builds on another server.

Please let me know the steps to set build on other server.

Thanks,
Mahak

Answer (score 0):

First of all: build script is stored on the TFS, so you're not copying it you just run them.
Second: to run the build on the separate server you need to install there TFSBuild. So you can have loads of build machines simply installing there TFSBuild and all necessary dll's. After that you only need to configure Build Agents in Build definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script which will execute after successful build.

This script should contain the code to copy the latest setup from the build drop location and copy it to the location where you want it to be copied.

Else you can create a windows task and schedule it for the same.